# Changing img src based on a variable's value in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

I am calling content from a JSON file using the jquery getJSON function, it is returning a collection called items and has two values:

1. interger value between 1 and 10
2. some text

Then in jquery each loop I am running through the array items and basd on the integer value trying to target an image tag to change its source, but it is not working.

Also I am using Bootstrap on the page to display the text content in the carousel which is working fine. Adding up the code below. As per my tests it seems that as the check is placed in jquery each, the system is running the whole loop in one go and the last iteration condition is applied to the div.

Can someone please help on how to stop this from happening?

```
$.getJSON("/samplecsat.json", function(result) {
  myarr = result.items;
  console.log("result is: " + JSON.stringify(result.items));
  console.log("total count is: " + result.items.length);
  total = result.items.length;
  $.each(myarr, function(i, field) {
    x = field["Survey Rating"];
    if (i == 0) {
      console.log("YAY its the first iteration" + i);
      if (x < 8) {
        dsat = dsat + 1;
        $('<div class="item active" style="color:red"><em>' + field["Customer Verbatim"] + '</em></div>').appendTo('.carousel-inner');
        $("#myCarousel").on('slide.bs.carousel', function() {
          $("#customersentiment").attr("src", "/csp/angry.gif");
        });
      } else {
        sat = sat + 1;
        $('<div class="item active" style="color:green">' + field["Customer Verbatim"] + '   </div>').appendTo('.carousel-inner');
        console.log("it is a csat with rating:" + " " + field["Survey Rating"])
        $("#myCarousel").on('slide.bs.carousel', function() {
          $("#customersentiment").attr("src", "/csp/happy.gif");
        });

      }
    } else {
      if (x < 8) {
        dsat = dsat + 1;
        $("#customersentiment").attr("src", "/csp/angry.gif");
        $('<div class="item" style="color:red"><em>' + field["Customer Verbatim"] + '</em></div>').appendTo('.carousel-inner');
        console.log(" its a dsat with rating:" + " " + field["Survey Rating"]);
        $("#myCarousel").on('slide.bs.carousel', function() {
          $("#customersentiment").attr("src", "/csp/angry.gif");
        });
      } else {
        sat = sat + 1;
        $("#customersentiment").attr("src", "");
        $('<div class="item" style="color:green"><em>' + field["Customer Verbatim"] + '</em></div>').appendTo('.carousel-inner');
        console.log("it is a csat with rating:" + " " + field["Survey Rating"])
        $("#myCarousel").on('slide.bs.carousel', function() {
          $("#customersentiment").attr("src", "/csp/happy.gif");
        });
      }
    }
  })
  console.log("Total DSATs by Js: " + dsat);
  console.log("Total CSATs by Js: " + sat);
  console.log("Total item count is: " + total);
  satpercentage = (sat * total / 100) * 100 + "%";
  console.log("percentage is: " + sat * total / 100);
  console.log("total is second one:" + total);
});
```

Comment: Way too difficult trying to read through that code with that indentation structure.

Comment: I can change the code to show what each condition does and can pinpoint which one is not working, if that helps.

Comment: Thanks devlin for taking the time to clean that up for him.

Comment: Is your question why is `$("#customersentiment").attr("src",...)` always being overwritten by the last iteration?

Comment: @BShaps yes, it seems the loop is completing and $("#customersentiment").attr("src",...) is affected by last iteration.